# pandas df to JSON with duplicate keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to convert a `df` with unique keys to a `JSON` file. The `pandas dataframe` looks like the below.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1,2,2,2,3,3], 'col2': ['a','b','c','','e','f'], 'col3': ['one','two','three','four','five','six']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> df
   col1 col2   col3
0     1    a    one
1     2    b    two
2     2    c  three
3     2        four
4     3    e   five
5     3    f    six
```

I want the JSON output to look like as follows:

```
{
    "1": [
      {
          "col2": "a",
          "col3": "one"
      }
  ],
    "2": [
      {
          "col2": "b",
          "col3": "two"
      },
      {
          "col2": "c",
          "col3": "three"
      },
      {
          "col2": "",
          "col3": "four"
       }
   ],
     "3": [
      {
          "col2": "e",
          "col3": "five"
      },
      {
          "col2": "f",
          "col3": "six"
      }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this in Python? My attempts are not working as the data contains duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create nested lists by convert `col1` to index, group by index values and all columns convert to `list`s in lambda function, last convert `Series`  to dictionary by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index('col1').groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_dict()
```

Another idea is use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = { k: v.to_dict(orient='records') for k, v in df.set_index(['col1']).groupby('col1')}
```

---

---

```
print (d)


{
    1: [{
        'col2': 'a',
        'col3': 'one'
    }],
    2: [{
        'col2': 'b',
        'col3': 'two'
    }, {
        'col2': 'c',
        'col3': 'three'
    }, {
        'col2': '',
        'col3': 'four'
    }],
    3: [{
        'col2': 'e',
        'col3': 'five'
    }, {
        'col2': 'f',
        'col3': 'six'
    }]
}
```

EDIT:

If need `col1` keys like strings:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)
d = df.set_index('col1').groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_dict()
```